# Create multiple virtualenv with different versions of python

Tags: python-3.x, version

Is it possible to create two different versions of virtualenv in python, while having single python installed python.

Can I create another virtualenv with say version 3.7.17 which is a lower version ?

My current looks something like this ?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3448]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\adi>python --version
Python 3.12.0
```

Created one venv with same version

```
(venv) C:\Users\adi>python --version
Python 3.12.0

(venv) C:\Users\adi>
```

Comment: I think the easiest way it is to use conda. It supports different version of python by design

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you have to install each Python version individually using the official installer.

Then using the Python Launcher you can select which version you want to use to create that venv.

```
py --list
py -3.7 -m venv .venv
```

There are other ways to use multiple python versions, like using conda or pyenv, but all of them will end up downloading the python binary.

Comment: I have the latest version, but older version installers now come with rc long term fix versions which I am not too sure will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a virtualenv for any version of Python that you have installed on your system.  Multiple virtual envs can exist at the same time for the same project, if that is what you want.  All you need to do is **use a unique directory name for the location of each environment**. When you create the environment, instead of naming it '.venv', you can name it '.venv39' (for example).  You can switch between environments at any time during development by simply running the 'activate.bat' script in the appropriate directory.

The version of Python that will appear in your virtual environment is determined by the version you used to create the environment.  For example, running `python3.9.exe -mvenv .venv39` (or whatever your Python 3.9 executable is called) will create an environment with that name and located in the `.venv39` directory.  You can do the same with other versions of Python.

Again, don't forget, you will need to have installed Python already using whatever installer is appropriate for your platform. This installation will get that version of Python onto your computer so that it can be used to create whatever virtual environments you need.

*note*: if you are developing a package where you want to ensure broad compatibility, using the tool **tox** is the standard way to do that, rather than managing multiple environments manually.